# Differences between testCompile and androidTestCompile for junit imports

Tags: android, import, android-gradle-plugin, junit4

What is the difference between these two import statements? (in `build.gradle`):

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confused about testCompile and androidTestCompile in Android Gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29021331/confused-about-testcompile-and-androidtestcompile-in-android-gradle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a great answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29024318/42303450) explaining the difference:

> Simply `testCompile` is the configuration for unit tests (located in `src/test`) and `androidTestCompile` is used for the test API (located in `src/androidTest`).
>
> ...
>
> The main distinction between the two is the `test` sourceset runs in a regular Java JVM, whereas the `androidTest` sourceset tests run on an Android device (or an emulator).