# Android JUnit run both Espresso and Robolectric test suites

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-espresso, robolectric

for a specific project we need to run both Espresso and Robolectric test suites but it seems that their dependencies seem to clash very badly.

Therefore my question, is it even possible to have them both or should we settle for another solution?

Our Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 24
        minSdkVersion 15
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
    }    
}

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'

    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1.4"

    compile ('com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0')
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29021331/confused-about-testcompile-and-androidtestcompile-in-android-gradle ? Also, according to documentation: http://robolectric.org/getting-started/ you need to use testCompile for Robolectric instead of androidTestCompile.

Comment: I tried it with `testCompile` but it results in the same. It just wouldn't compile.

Comment: Can you also try to use testCompile for both JUnit and robolectric? I've tried same build.gradle file on mine machine with buildToolsVersion "24.0.3" and it compiled.

Comment: Can you post exactly error that you get?

Answer (score 1):

You can have them  both, but you need to separate them into separate test packages.

Your robolectric tests should belong to the `test` package, while espresso tests should reside in the `androidTest`. Your dependencies will also be prefixed according to the packages (i.e robolectric dependencies will be `testCompile`, while espresso tests will be `androidTestCompile`).

This split is required due to the nature of both robolectric and espresso tests. Robolectric being a unit testing framework has android sdk fully (to some extent) mocked which allows the execution of the tests in JVM, while espresso requires "real" android for tests to be executed.

[This guide](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/start/index.html) from google covers the test set up in more details.